# WKWebView's Context menu "Download Image" menu item not responding....

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, contextmenu, wkwebview

Image download from right click "Context Menu" not responding in the web page loaded in WKWebview. If any body knows help me to identify which delegate method will receive this call or is there any manual implementation needed to get this option work.


```
App:Mac Application.  Language : Objective C. SDK: Xcode
```

[image: Scrren Shot here]

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept context menu items of the WKWebView class by subclassing it and implementing the willOpenMenu method like this:

```
class MyWebView: WKWebView {
    override func willOpenMenu(_ menu: NSMenu, with event: NSEvent) {
        for menuItem in menu.items {
            if menuItem.identifier?.rawValue == "WKMenuItemIdentifierDownloadImage" ||
            menuItem.identifier?.rawValue == "WKMenuItemIdentifierDownloadLinkedFile" {
                menuItem.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```